# How to install logstash-input-jmx in RHEL?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, rubygems, logstash, jmx

Has anyone installed **logstash-input-jmx** (or any other "community" plugin for Logstash) in RHEL?

How did you manage the Ruby/gem dependencies?

After installing a recent version of Ruby, RubyGems, and Rails, the development/runtime gem dependencies have to be resolved, but attempting to install any of the gems mentioned in [here](https://rubygems.org/gems/logstash-input-jmx), would lead to endless missing dependencies ...

Are there any packaged versions of Logstash JMX plugin around?

Thanks,

Babak.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the house of fun. What I did was, which may be out of your scope but it might help....

`$logstash_location/bin/logstash-plugin list`

(as you might expect this shows what can be installed to your instance)

`$logstash_location/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-jmx`

The plugin itself should resolve its own dependencies. I was having all sort of problems in Docker, but I had to build my Logstash tarball external to the machine. Make sure connectivity is ok too. It's a service, not local to your machine.

Comment: That's the problem Marc: logstash-plugin is a shell script which doesn't seem to be compatible with RHEL, because when you run it, it immediately executes the "setup" program and then complains about the second command in the shell script, which reads as: . "$(cd `dirname $0`/..; pwd)/bin/logstash.lib.sh"

Comment: I ran it on CentOS 7 with no issues. Maybe try another VM and then just tar up your package and bring it across?

Comment: I'm not running it on a VM. It's a real blade. Apparently (according to the "issues" page in the github repository) that matters.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://mattharris.org/2016/03/22/logstash-install-amazon-linux/) clearly describes the steps required to install a "community" logstash plugin, and can be used to install jmx plugin on RHEL. I've tried it on RHEL 7.3.

The main thing to consider is that in RHEL 7.3 the logstash can be found under /usr/share/logstash/ rather than /opt/logstash